# jQuery Star Rating - Hover Multiple Rows

Tags: jquery, hover, row, rating

I'm a total newbie when it comes to PHP/JAVA, but nontheless, I got the jQuery Star Rating Plugin working on my website and to show text next to the stars when i hover it.

Now I want to add another row of stars, but I only want the text to show of the row that i'm hovering.

Example
ROW 1 Stars - HOVER TEXT
ROW 2 Stars - HOVER TEXT

When I hover row 1 or 2, the text will show in both rows. Any idea how i can solve this.

Java code in my header

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.wesley').rating({
        focus: function(value, link) {
            // 'this' is the hidden form element holding the current value
            // 'value' is the value selected
            // 'element' points to the link element that received the click.
            var tip = $('#hover-test, #hover-test2');
            tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
            tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
        },
        blur: function(value, link) {
            var tip = $('#hover-test');
            $('#hover-test, #hover-test2').html(tip[0].data || '');
        }
    });
});​
</script>
```

What shows the text and is next to the stars

```
<span id="hover-test2" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;">Hover tips will appear in here</span>
```

Comment: Post the full HTML source containing the rows of stars etc... Looks to me like you are creating an even that will listen to either row. You will need to create two separate listeners, one for each row that will handle each independently.

Comment: Appologies, I thought they were the same :(

Comment: @sbohan Will the link to the webppage work?

Comment: http://www.datingindepender.nl/schrijf-review-relatieplanet/

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have the following code in the wrong place, you need to have the matching span#hover-text directly underneath where you have the stars with the matching class name.

```
<div id="frm_bg_star">
<label class="frm_primary_label">
Beoordeel<span class="frm_required">&nbsp*</span>
    <div class="frm_description">Beoordeel de verschillende aspecten van Relatieplanet.nl</div>
 </label>
<div id="star-rating-top"><div id="star-rating-word"><a class="tooltip">
   <img src="/wp-content/themes/Hector/images/icon_tooltip.gif"></img>&nbsp
<span>Hoe was het aanbod van profielen. Waren deze actief en had je het vermoeden of dit geen nep-profielen waren? </span>
</a>Singles Aanbod</div><div id="star-rating"><div class="alignleft frm_10radio ">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[26]" id="field_26-1" value="Option 1 text"   class="scale required wesley star" />
</div>   
<div class="alignleft frm_10radio ">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[26]" id="field_26-2" value="Option 2 text"   class="scale required wesley star" />
</div>   
<div class="alignleft frm_10radio ">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[26]" id="field_26-3" value="Option 3 text"   class="scale required wesley star" />
</div>   
<div class="alignleft frm_10radio ">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[26]" id="field_26-4" value="Option 4 text"   class="scale required wesley star" />
</div>   
<div class="alignleft frm_10radio  frm_last">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[26]" id="field_26-5" value="Option 5 text"   class="scale required wesley star" />
</div>   
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. In the Javascript (header) You define a class of the row of stars, next to that you say what ID it needs to use to show your text.

However, I can give each row of stars their own unique CLASS, but I still have only 1 class defined in my JAVASCRIPT Header.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to define a second class that points to an ID in the Javascript?